# homestead up not working after vagrant up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

The "homestead up" command is not working on Ubuntu 14.10. These are the outcome of that command:

> /home/omicronit/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:18:in `read': No such file or directory - /home/omicronit/.homestead/Homestead.yaml (Errno::ENOENT)
>       from /home/omicronit/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead/Vagrantfile:18:in`block in '
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `call'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in`load'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in load'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in`each'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:97:in `block in load'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in`each'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:94:in `load'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in`initialize'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:691:in `new'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:691:in`vagrantfile'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:441:in `host'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:207:in`block in action_runner'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `call'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in`run'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:428:in `hook'
>       from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:673:in`unload'
>       from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:177:in `ensure in <main>'
>       from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/bin/vagrant:177:in`'

Answer (score 0):

`homestead` can not read your `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` file.

Make sure it the directory (`~/.homestead`) and the file (`Homestead.yaml`) are present and readable.

If it is missing you can get a stub [here](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/src/stubs/Homestead.yaml).

P.S. If you've just installed Homestead then most likely your forgot to perform a mandatory step during [installation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#installation-and-setup) (see *Cloning The Homestead Repository* subsection):

run `bash init.sh` from a directory where you have clonned Homestead.